# Cannot redeclare CheckEvenOdd()

Tags: php

Ошибка:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare CheckEvenOdd() (previously declared in
>   D:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\functions.php:2) in
>   D:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\functions.php on line 8

```
function CheckEvenOdd($value) {
  if(($value%2) == 0) {
    return 'even';
  } else {
    return 'odd';
  }
}
```

Как исправить? Нигде больше не задается функция. Вызывается она так:

```
$week = CheckEvenOdd(date('W'));

if($week == 'even') {
  $above = ' class="active"';
  $below = '';
} elseif($week == 'odd') {
  $below = ' class="active"';
  $above = '';
}
```

Comment: А что у вас на второй строке файла functions.php?

Comment: Вторая задаёт функцию, 8 скобки закрытия функции.

Answer (score 1):

У вас так или иначе дважды подключается файл с этой функцией, поэтому при втором проходе интерпретатор пытается ее повторно объявить, что и приводит к вышеуказанной ошибке. Если есть самописные автозагрузчики, проверьте в первую очередь их; еслси дело не в этом, убедитесь, что вы не подключаете файл дважды или что он не подключается в цикле.